# Group by not including "null" data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I am trying to calculate status wise statistics but the problem is when I do group by then I am not getting `"null"` statistics.

```
Parent:
Id   Status
1    Processed
2    Hold
3    Review
4    Closed
5    Rejected
6    Draft

Child :
Id    UserId    ParentId
1     100       1
2     100       1
3     100       1
4     100       1

5     100       2
6     100       2
7     100       2

8     100       3
4     100       3

8     100       4
4     100       4

9     100       5
10    100       6

11    100       null
12    100       null
```

**Expected Output :**

```
Processed = 4
Hold = 3
Review = 2
Closed = 2
Rejected = 1
Draft = 1
Null = 2
```

Query:

```
var data = (from c in context.Child
            where c.UserId == 100 &&
            (c.Parent ==null || c.Parent.IsActive)
            group c by new
            {
                c.ParentId,
                c.Parent.Status
            } into g
            select new StatusWiseStatsResult
            {
                Status = g.Key.Status,
                Statistics = g.Count(),
                Id = g.Key.ParentId == null ? 0 : (int)g.Key.ParentId
            }).OrderByDescending(c => c.Statistics).ToList();
```

But it doesn't return that "null" count of 2 in above query.

Can anyone tell me what is the issue and the fix please?

Comment: Not your issue, but the where `where c.UserId == 100 && c.UserId == 100`, you have that condition twice; maybe a type-o?

Comment: @Codexer Sorry it was a typo. Thanks for pointing out. Updated the question :)

Comment: Which database provider is this? I tried a similar query with EF6 + Sql Server and couldn't reproduce it.

Comment: @GertArnold I am using Sql Server

Comment: Is this the exact query from your code base? Other predicates may easily turn an outer join into a de-facto inner join.

Comment: @GertArnold There are 1 or 2 extra filters but that's on the Child table itself. I am only referring "IsActive" and "Status" column from the Parent table. Interestingly, I have the SQL query with Left join which gives the expected output but I don't know whats the issue with Linq query

Comment: @GertArnold I have tried with explicit Left join with Linq query but it's not giving me the "Null" count too.

Comment: I'm afraid you're gonna have to reproduce your case more closely here. I'm pretty sure that when you just do `from c in context.Child where c.Parent ==null || c.Parent.IsActive select c` you'll get results where Parents are `null`. That's means that the rest of the query somewhere cancels the outer join.

Answer (score 0):

see this line here

```
 (c.Parent ==null || c.Parent.IsActive)
```

take it out. then do a check to see if c.Parent.IsActive != false

```
 .Where(x => c.Parent != null ? c.Parent.IsActive : true)
```

Comment: Sorry but if I remove c.Parent=null then it does not include the data where ParentId is null but I want all the data even when Parent Id is null.

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow oh -- I think I miss read it as you wanted to exclude cases of null, if you want nulls to be included then you can't check that parent is active in the original query

Comment: Yes, I want to include "null" counts and this "null" is the issue in my query. Bdw, I haven't downvoted your answer just so you know :)

Comment: oh thanks -- yeah I have over 60k the days of me caring about a downvote are long gone.